# The application Google Chrome has closed unexpectedly

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I recently started getting these warnings on my Ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any recent update or new application/package installed?

Comment: No, I haven't installed anything recently

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 16 GB Which I upgraded last week. It was 8 previously

Comment: Does it start properly if you start from terminal e.g. command google-chrome --profile-directory=/tmp/profile. If so, your profile is corrupt